# How to connect Canon iP110 WiFi printer to a Huawei E5331 Hotspot/Toshiba Chromebook?

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, printer, hotspot

The WiFi hotspot I am using is a Huawei E5331, and it does not have a WPS button function. So is it possible to connect a Canon iP110 WiFi printer to a WiFi hotspot device without the use of a WPS connection?

I have also been trying to find ways to connect my Canon iP110 WiFi printer to my Toshiba Chromebook. I have connected to the printer from the Chromebook through WiFi Setup, but cannot proceed with any installation of drivers or app's for canon iP110. Is it even possible to print from a Chromebook through to the iP110 printer without any drivers installed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible.

On the Canon iP110 Printer. you have 3 buttons.
- The power button
- The Resume/Cancel button
- The Wi-Fi button

Hold the Wi-Fi button down until the power button light flashes 3 times.  then go to your wifi network and wait until you see *******-iP110Series

Put a blanco paper in the printer and hold the Resume/Cancel button down until the power button light flashes 6 times.

The printer will print the Network Configuration Page. On that page there is a password. Try to connect with your printer and fill in the given password

Comment: Additional note: The standard wifi password is the serial number found on the back of your device.